# What's the Questions Asked to Accepted Answer Ratio?

Tags: discussion

Usually on the front page I see most questions with definitive answers but some will never get accepted. I was just curious how many question we have versus how many accept answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- according to [questions tab](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions) we have 38481 questions
- according to [`hasaccepted:yes` search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasaccepted:yes) 20628 questions have accepted answer

20628 / 38481 = **~54%**

Comment: That's much higher than I would have guessed. I wonder how that stacks up to other exchanges.

Answer (score 6):

[My calcuation](http://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/query/147888/accept-ratio-for-a-site) works out to the same answer as [Rarst's](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3695/35055).  Looking at a few other sites, WordPress seems very close to average.  The maximum ratio (79%) is held by French and the minimum ratio (26%) belongs to Patents.  The distribution looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It is curious that we fall close to average since our overall answered rate (accepted or upvoted) has been historically low-ish. I wonder if we are slacking on upvoting viable but not accepted answers.